# How to redirect a navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have all my stacks in my **AppNavigator** located in my file **routes.js**, and im rendering it on my main file **App.js**, I just want the user go directly to **'Home'** stack if he is already authenticated (`isAuthenticated: true`). Can someone help me, please? Others solutions for this problem are welcome! It's possible to acess the `isAuthenticated` value on my login page and do the navigation there? if it's, how?

My current code:

> **routes.js**

```js
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthenticationNavigator,
  Home: MainNavigator,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Auth'}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer
```

> **App.js**

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticationReady: false,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      test: true,
    };
    // Iniciando firebase... source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNZks2j2Qaw
    if (!firebase.apps.length) { firebase.initializeApp(ApiKeys.FirebaseConfig); }
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);
  }

  onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {  //Funcao chamada toda vez que ha uma mundança login/logout
    this.setState({isAuthenticationReady: true}); //avisa que autenticaçao foi feita
    this.setState({isAuthenticated: !!user}); //se o user for 'null' e pq ta deslogado, senao, ta logado
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticationReady) {
      return (
        <>
          <AppContainer /> //this part i will do later
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#121212" />
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ? ( this.props.navigation.navigate("Main") ) : ( this.props.navigation.navigate("Main") ) }
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
{this.state.isAuthenticated ? ( <AppContainer /> ) : ( <AppContainer /> ) }
```

where is `<AppContainer />` i wish it was `this.props.navigation.navigate()`, but it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you to just return "AppContainer" in App.js. And do all the auth related checking in AuthenticationNavigator component. And navigate from AuthenticationNavigator to Home using this.props.navigation.navigate("Home").

Or if you want to maintain the same code. You can do "MainNavigator" component instead of this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");

Comment: I moved the auth code to the LoginScreen.js and now i can do what i wanted, thank you